# 2D Integration With Quadratic Argument of Delta Function

Tags: integration, calculus

> 1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data. I have a 2D integral that contains a delta function:
>    $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp{-((x_2-x_1)^2+a x_2^2+b x_1^2-c x_2+d x_1+e)}\delta(p x_1^2-q x_2^2) dx_1 dx_2,$$
>    where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are variables, and $a,b,c,d,e,p$ and $q$ are some real constants.

2. Relevant equations

   How can one integrate this without resulting in poles. Because integral over, for example, $x_1$ leads to a pole, given the property of delta function.
3. The attempt at a solution
   If inside the delta function, the argument would be $x_1^2+x_2^2$, and not $x_1^2-x_2^2$, then one could go to polar coordinates, and get rid of the poles coming from the delta function integral. Sadly, this is not the case here.
   Further one can get rid of pole by going into hyperbolic coordinates $x_1=RCosh(\theta)$ and  $x_2=RSinh(\theta)$. The R integral can be done exactly because the poles cancel out due to Jacobian. However, the integral over ##\theta## then becomes unbounded. So this method also has a problem. Is there a smarter way to perform integral with quadratic argument of delta function without encountering poles?

Comment: Please correct the brackets.

Comment: Not sure if this is, strictly speaking, a physics question! Maybe this should be migrated?

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: What is your definition of $\delta(p x_1^2-qx_2^2)$ and more generally $\delta(\phi(x_1,x_2))$ ?

Comment: definition of $\delta(\phi(x_1,x_2))$ is simply evaluating the remainder of the function in the integral at $\phi(x_1,x_2)=0$